# Likely slow copper pipe leak in wall

Tags: plumbing, flooring

We noticed our wood floors were beginning to feel a little uneven/warped. Not wet or visible, just to feel. Pulled the fridge out and heard water dripping on water behind the wall. Investigated and ended up cutting out some drywall and found a 2 cm puddle between studs and as I traced up I feel a constant small amount of water on the copper pipe. I haven’t been brave enough to keep cutting out drywall to get to the leak, looks higher up. In retrospect this probably has been going on for a few weeks slowly.
I’m thinking of waiting til tomorrow so as to not make an “emergency” call with the higher price over the weekend. Source isn’t found but puddle is dried up and I’ve got rags catching through water running around the edge of the pipe so it’s not getting to floor, and turning off water to house overnight.
Is the source most probably a 90’ angle turn in the piping? Any thoughts on my action plan? Got heaters and fans running and going to see if neighbors can lend a dehumidifier, anything else for the floors?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to open the wall more to get a picture where the leak is, and post it here in your question using the Edit link and the Mountain icon for posting pictures. Then some solid help could be provided. A lot of damage can come from a water leak, much more expensive than a new piece of drywall. Can you turn the water off that feeds this pipe without turning the whole house off?

Comment: Step 1: find the leak.  So, you cut some drywall, but only enough to see the puddle on the framing bottom plate?  Is your hole big enough to stick your cell phone inside and take a pic upward (I'm assuming you don't have an endoscopic camera)?

Comment: A small drywall patch is pretty much the same amount of work as a large drywall patch. Keep cutting!

Comment: And cheaper doing it yourself than paying plumber fees to cut drywall.